# Postgres DB Password not being set in Kubernetes script

Tags: postgresql, docker, kubernetes

For some reason, the postgres instance isn't being locked down with a password using the following kubernetes script.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
    name: postgres
    labels:
        name: postgres
spec:
    replicas: 1
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          name: postgres
      spec:
        containers:
          - resources:
            image: postgres:9.4
            name: postgres
            env:
              - name: DB_PASS
                value: password
              - name: PGDATA
                value: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
            ports:
              - containerPort: 5432
                name: postgres
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
                name: postgres-persistent-storage
        volumes:
          - name: postgres-persistent-storage
            gcePersistentDisk:
              pdName: postgres-disk
              fsType: ext4
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docker hub documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) for the postgres image you should be using the environment variable `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` instead of `DB_PASSWORD`.

Comment: I should have mentioned I actually tried this as well and it didn't work.  I'm wondering if the format of my script is wrong?

Comment: I figured out the problem. You have to specify the POSTGRES_PASSWORD the first time. If you don't, you cannot add it later.

Comment: Can you explain? Did you try to change the yaml file and patch the object? If you changed the yaml you could also do a [kubectl rolling update](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_rolling-update.html) to apply your changes because it replaces the current pods with new pods with the updated configuration.

Comment: I had to delete the pod and the volume.  If I left the volume, it wouldn't pick up the added password.